# How to cancel an AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have setup an alarmManager as follows:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(TopActivity.this, RecordActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra(Utils.KEY_RECORD_TIME, recordLength);
    intent.putExtra(Utils.KEY_REC_START_TIME, start);

    saveTimeAndLength(start, recordLength);

    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(TopActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);
```

The following is supposed to cancel it, but it always fail. What am I missing?

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(TopActivity.this, RecordActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra(Utils.KEY_RECORD_TIME, start);
intent.putExtra(Utils.KEY_REC_START_TIME, recordLength);

PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(TopActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
try {
    alarmManager.cancel(pintent);
    Log.e(TAG, "Cancelling all pending intents");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "AlarmManager update was not canceled. " + e.toString());
}
```

I have read lots of answers on StackOverflow but still could not figure out what's the problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Someone already mentioned that the Extra data keys are inverted (start and recordLength)?`intent.putExtra(Utils.KEY_RECORD_TIME, recordLength);
    intent.putExtra(Utils.KEY_REC_START_TIME, start);` vs. `intent.putExtra(Utils.KEY_RECORD_TIME, start);
intent.putExtra(Utils.KEY_REC_START_TIME, recordLength);` - it should not cause filtering trouble though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post my answer here hoping that would help others saving some time.
Somehow adding the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` in both sides solve the problem.

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(TopActivity.this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

solved the problem.
**Setting Alarm**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(TopActivity.this, RecordActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra(Utils.KEY_RECORD_TIME, recordLength);
    intent.putExtra(Utils.KEY_REC_START_TIME, start);

    saveTimeAndLength(start, recordLength);

    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(TopActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);
```

**Cancel Alarm**

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(TopActivity.this, RecordActivity.class);

PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(TopActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
try {
    alarmManager.cancel(pintent);
    Log.e(TAG, "Cancelling all pending intents");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "AlarmManager update was not canceled. " + e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For AlarmManager to cancel an event, it needs to compare the two Intents.

This is achieved through filterEquals (Intent other) method which says

> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent
>   resolution (filtering). That is, if their action, data, type, class,
>   and categories are the same. This does not compare any extra data
>   included in the intents.

I am not sure why it does not matches when the class is same.

I too had the same problem, to overcome with that I have set a data also.

See if this helps u.

**EDITED**

while setting up the Alarm

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(TopActivity.this, RecordActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra(Utils.KEY_RECORD_TIME, recordLength);
    intent.putExtra(Utils.KEY_REC_START_TIME, start);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("yourappscheme", "alarm", null)); 
    saveTimeAndLength(start, recordLength);

    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(TopActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);
```

And when need to cancel

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(TopActivity.this, RecordActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra(Utils.KEY_RECORD_TIME, start);
intent.putExtra(Utils.KEY_REC_START_TIME, recordLength);
intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("yourappscheme", "alarm", null)); 

PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(TopActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
try {
    alarmManager.cancel(pintent);
    Log.e(TAG, "Cancelling all pending intents");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "AlarmManager update was not canceled. " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an idea how you overcome your problem. Everything I do , doesnt seem to work.@Vivek Khandelwal I have even saved the intent I set in the alarm and cancel it but it doesnt work.

Comment: I havent tried your method, somehow adding the flag PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT solved my problem. Pretty weird!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your pending intent and then cancel it

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent updateServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyPendingIntentService.class);
PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, updateServiceIntent, 0);

// Cancel alarms
try {
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingUpdateIntent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "AlarmManager update was not canceled. " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: I think I am doing the same thing!