# Cancel AlarmManager not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm trying to cancel an alarm when user changes a checkbox at Settings screen.

What I'm doing is : send a broadcast at my `AlarmReceiver` class with an intent extra boolean variable to force the alarm to cancel like :

```
   Intent alarmIntent = new Intent("PACKAGE_ALARM");
    alarmIntent.putExtra("cancel", true);
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(alarmIntent);
```

and inside the `onReceive()` method :

```
    if (intent.hasExtra("cancel")) {
        cancelAlarm(context);
    }
```

where `cancelAlarm` is :

```
private void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getService(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

where the Alarm I have already set up is :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmrService.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent
            .getService(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, startTime.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
```

I think what I have done is correct so I don;t know why when I call cancel method and use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` from my command line I can still read :

```
+2ms running, 0 wakeups, 1 alarms: u0a74:PACKAGEr
  *alarm*:PACKAGE/.reminders.AlarmService
u0a74:PACKAGE +2ms running, 0 wakeups:
+2ms 0 wakes 1 alarms: *alarm*:PACKAGE/.reminders.AlarmService
```

EDIT : full code

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = AlarmReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 999;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onReceive MESA STHN onRECEIVE");

    if (intent.hasExtra("cancel")) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive CANCEL");
        cancelAlarm(context);
    }
    if (intent.hasExtra("schedule")) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive SCHEDULE");
        scheduleAlarm(context);
    }

    //Schedule alarm on BOOT_COMPLETED
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        scheduleAlarm(context);
    }
}

/* Schedule the alarm based on user preferences */
public static void scheduleAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager manager = AlarmManagerProvider.getAlarmManager(context);

    String keyReminder = context.getString(R.string.pref_key_reminder);
    String keyAlarm = context.getString(R.string.pref_key_alarm);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    boolean enabled = preferences.getBoolean(keyReminder, false);

    //Intent to trigger
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class);
    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent
            .getService(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Log.i("ALARM", "AlarmReceiver 111111");

    if (enabled) {
        Log.i("ALARM", "AlarmReceiver 2222222");
        //Gather the time preference
        Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            String alarmPref = preferences.getString(keyAlarm, "12:00");
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
            startTime.setTime(format.parse(alarmPref));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to determine alarm start time", e);
            return;
        }

        //Start at the preferred time
        //If that time has passed today, set for tomorrow
        if (Calendar.getInstance().after(startTime)) {
            startTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, startTime.getTimeInMillis(), operation);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "scheduleAlarm MESA STO CANCEL");
        manager.cancel(operation);
    }
}

private void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getService(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    // either value we have to cancel the previous alarm
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}

}
```

EDIT 2 : code from SettingsFragment where I listen for changes in user preferences :

```
    listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

            String keyReminder = getActivity().getString(R.string.pref_key_reminder);
            String keyAlarm = getActivity().getString(R.string.pref_key_alarm);
            boolean enabled = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(keyReminder, false);
            String alarmTime = sharedPreferences.getString(keyAlarm, "");

            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent("PACKAGE_ALARM");

            if (key.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_key_reminder))) {


                if (enabled) {
                    // schedule
                    Log.i("SETTINGS", "SCHEDULE ");
                    alarmIntent.putExtra("schedule", true);
                    getActivity().sendBroadcast(alarmIntent);
                } else  {
                    // cancel
                    Log.i("SETTINGS", "CANCEL");
                    alarmIntent.putExtra("cancel", true);
                    getActivity().sendBroadcast(alarmIntent);
                }


            } else if (key.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_key_alarm))) {

                if (enabled) {
                    // update
                } else {
                    // nothing
                }

            }

        }

    };
```

and receiver's entry in Manifest :

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".reminders.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="PACKAGE_ALARM" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: The `Intent` you're using to cancel is not the same `Intent` used to set the alarm.

Comment: @MikeM. hmmm...good catch!Thanks! How am I going to keep the previous intent in my Broadcast Receiver class for later use?

Comment: You don't really need to keep it. Just create it and the `PendingIntent` to be the same each time. If `REQUEST_CODE` is the same in both of those snippets, then the only difference is that the cancel `Intent` targets `ReminderService.class`, whereas the alarm was set with an `Intent` targeting `AlarmrService.class` (I guess that's a typo).

Comment: Like @MikeM  said, no need to save the previous intent.
Remember having the same question a couple years ago.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536486/how-to-cancel-an-alarmmanager

Comment: @MikeM. yes that's a typo. But I have just changed it so both `PendingIntent`s are the same and still it does not cancels the alarm.

Comment: I pasted the `AlarmReceiver` class in case you can notice what's wrong. AS you can see both `PendingIntent`s are similar

Comment: It's really hard to tell what's going on, and what exactly you're trying to do. What is `AlarmReceiver`'s function, exactly? That is, why are you broadcasting to a Receiver to schedule and cancel alarms? Why not just call those methods directly? Also, where does `AlarmService` come into play here? Are you trying to set an alarm for that, or for `ReminderService`?

Comment: `AlarmService` is for creating a notification. I needed the Receiver class so I can listen for boot events and schedule again the alarm.

Comment: I have added also the code from the `SettingsFragment` where I'm listening for preference changes and I then call `AlarmReceiver`. Thanks for your time.

Comment: OK, so the alarms are for `ReminderService` only now. How are you determining that it's not cancelled? Are you sure the `cancelAlarm()` method is being called? And, as mentioned, why not just call that method directly? Make it `public static`, and call `AlarmReceiver.cancelAlarm(getActivity());`. That's surely more solid than using system-wide broadcasts and extras.

Comment: I made `cancelAlarm` static and not I'm calling it directly. Same for `scheduleAlarm` method. I can tell that the alarm is not canceled cause I'm running : `adb shell " dumpsys alarm | grep PACKAGE"` and I can see the same output : ` +1ms running, 0 wakeups, 1 alarms: u0a77:PACKAGE ... etc... `

Comment: And you're certain that `cancelAlarm()` is being called? And `scheduleAlarm()` is not being called again after that somehow? Are you checking on the log prints in `onSharedPreferenceChanged()`? You sure your logic there is correct? Are you sure you're not getting things mixed up between the alarms and the reminders? 'cause I gotta say I don't know what the difference is there, and it seems like that was part of the original issue.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes I'm sure about the flow. I'm checking the log messages in logcat. If there's another call I should at least see some messages in logcat.

Comment: Well, I got nothin' else. That's how you cancel an alarm. If you're certain the coding logic is correct, and it should do what you want, then you might try cleaning/rebuilding, especially if you're using Instant Run. Other than that, I would have to guess that something is off in your logic somewhere.

Comment: Btw, you might want to update your question to reflect the latest changes - like the current adb output, etc. - just so other users don't think you still have the wrong class in the `cancel()` call.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks Mike for your help. I tried clean/rebuild and I'm also checking in another device. If nothing changes I'll try updating the question and the question title. Thanks again for your time!